# Is sky diving on topic here?

Tags: discussion

[What is the purpose of D-Bag in skydiving parachute?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15812/what-is-the-purpose-of-d-bag-in-skydiving-parachute)
And a few others popup to me. This is not about aviation (plane,glider etc). This is about sky diving. So should these be asked here or OP should look for another SE site? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Skydiving is related to aviation. IMO, it is like saying that landing gears are tires, so how come tires are related to aviation, they should be related to motor vehicles.

Answer (score 6):

I think there has been a  discussion before on this topic (I can't find where, perhaps in chat) and IIRC the consensus was that skydiving is on-topic.

And it should be. Skydiving is a form of aviation.

Comment: We even have a skydiving tag and have a parachute rigger who has given some very good answers here.

Comment: @Lnafziger Maybe you're thinking about the [question on paragliding](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/358/62)? If that's on-topic - and I agree that it is - then there's no reasonable argument for excluding skydiving. Parachutes are just paragliders with a terrible glide ratio :-)